# PHP Change Function Query to be Direct Query Without Call The Function

Tags: php

I have an PHP code function `get_news()`.

get_news function

```
function get_news(){
    if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_post WHERE post_id<>1 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 50')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $return .= '<p>id: '.$r->post_id.' | '.htmlspecialchars($r->post).'</p>';

        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

Now, I have 1 php file for fetching the data

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST['counter']) && (int)$_POST['counter']!=$data['current']){
//the counters are diffrent so get new message list
$data['news'] = '';
$data['news'] .= $db->get_news();
$data['update'] = true;
}
```

My question is, how can I change the `$db->get_news();` to be a direct query without call the function?

Comment: You simply can't assign `data['news']` a value without call the corrispective function (I mean, the query function). And, why you're worried about? Or you don't wanna to call `get_news()`? To me is a good programming paradigm to separate that snippe of code from the rest of your application, why don't you think the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this
$news = '';
if($result = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM tb_post WHERE post_id<>1 ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 50')){
        $return = '';
        while($r = $result->fetch_object()){
            $news .= '<p>id: '.$r->post_id.' | '.htmlspecialchars($r->post).'</p>';

        }
    }

$data['news'] = $news;
$data['update'] = true;
```